# Comparator expalantion in Kotlin

Tags: sorting, pointers, kotlin, data-structures, collections

```
val list = listOf(7,3,5,9,1,3)
list.sortedWith(Comparator<Int>{ a, b ->
    when {
        a > b -> 1
        a < b -> -1
        else -> 0
    }
})
```

Answer - [1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9]

> Above code sort the given list in Kotlin.Can someone explain how this comparator works and do the sorting.I'm struggling to understand how this list gets sorted. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: a `Comparator` tells sorting &c methods how to compare two objects, i.e. what order they should be in.  The code in the question doesn't actually need one, because `Int`s already have a natural ordering.  But it's perfectly good code, and illustrates what to do for objects that don't.

This is explained pretty well in the docs for [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)…  (In general, the docs are pretty good for all the Java standard library, so that's a good place to start.)

Some objects have a ‘natural ordering’; for example, there's a very obvious ordering for numbers (numerical order) and strings (dictionary order).  In Java and Kotlin, that's indicated by the objects implementing the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.  All the standard sorting, ordering, &c functions know from that what order to use.

But what about objects that don't have a natural order?  In that case, if you want to sort them or do anything that involves ordering, you'll have to explain what order to use.  You do that by providing an object implementing `Comparator`.

This has a single method `int compare(T o1, T o2)`: the implementation has to decide whether `o1` is less than, greater than, or equal to `o2`.  It does this by returning a negative number if `o1` < `o2`, zero if `o1` = `o2`, or a positive number if `o1` > `o2`.

That's what the code in the question does.

The `List.sortedWith()` method uses the comparator to create a sorted version of the list.  The sorting algorithm it uses will determine exactly which objects it compares, but for example it might start by comparing the first two items in the list: 7 and 3.  It would call the comparator with `compare(7, 3)`, and the comparator will return a positive number (in this case 1) to indicate that 7 should come after 3 in the list.  It would then continue processing the list and making further comparisons until it can produce a list in order.

As I said, in this case there's no need to write a comparator, because `Int`s already have a natural ordering!  So you could simply use `list.sorted()`.  (That would then use `Int`'s own `compareTo()` method, which works in a similar way.)

But there's no harm in using your own comparator, and the code in the question shows how it could be done.